# Как заменить теги одной строки тегами другой строки?

Tags: php

Есть 2 строки:

Я `<span>люблю</span>` яблочный `<span>сок</span>`

I `<span>like</span>` apple `<span>juice</span>`

Как теги одной строки заменить тегами другой строки? Чтобы получилось

Я `<span>like</span>` яблочный `<span>juice</span>`

Количество тегов `span` в строке заранее неизвестно.

Comment: Просто подряд? Первый на первый, второй на второй?

Comment: да, подряд, по порядку